# The meaning of Glyph

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I don't quite get what Glyph really is. I read an wiki article, where it gives an example below. but I don't understand why lower-case i is not a glyph in Latin alphabet in this case. Can someone help me to understand? Any further explanations and more examples are appreciated.

> For example, in most languages written in any variety of the Latin
>   alphabet the dot on a lower-case i is not a **glyph** because it does not
>   convey any distinction, and an i in which the dot has been
>   accidentally omitted is still likely to be recognized correctly. In
>   Turkish, however, it is a glyph, because that language has two
>   distinct versions of the letter i, with and without a dot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a technical term in typography, not concerned with the learning of English.

Comment: It didn't say the **i** is not a glyph, by the way. It said the **dot** is not a glyph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example paragraph you provided is correct.

A glyph is a symbol representing a specific sound, idea, or concept.  For example, the U.S. copyright symbol © is a glyph.  The "c" from the circle used independently is also a glyph, representing a specific sound in spoken language.  However, the circle (for this example) is not a glyph because it is not associated with a specific sound, idea, or concept.

This is why the dot over an "i" is not a glyph in the English language.  By itself it has no sound, idea, or concept.

However, it is important to realize there may be a different definition in computing.  While in standard English there is a glyph "i" that may be represented as a capital "I" and an italic *"i"* and everything under the sun.  These are often considered stylistic expressions of the glyph "i".  However, computers are forced to separate all these things due to how data is stored and represented graphically on a screen.  So, to a programmer, every expression of a character is a totally unique glyph.